# How to print window contents, and how to avoid the layout being shifted?

Tags: javascript, php, windows, visual-studio, printing

What is the simplest way to provide the Print function when developing (a) a web application using PHP, and (b) a Windows application using Visual C++ or C#, so that the contents in a specific area of the window can be printed out by a printer, or converted to .ps or .pdf file format if a PostScript or PDF writer is already installed?

For web application I have read using JavaScript, which is acceptable for me, but the most important issue is to avoid shifting of words or graphics in the printout when compared with the layout being shown in the window area. Just some start-up pointers will be good enough for me, since I am not asking for specific code solution. I am not sure if this is actually the same as writing virtual printer driver, so pardon me if I am repeating the question.

Comment: You should produce the PDF from the coordinates on the server